# Display center of mass, what is the meaning of the green lines?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi.

Still working on my inertia issues, I wonder what is the meaning of the green lines displayed in the center of mass view:

[image: image description]

Precisely here:

[image: image description]

It is related to the orientation of the inertia, but I did not find it in the documentation and I do not find it obvious.

Thx.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4629/display-center-of-mass,-what-is-the-meaning-of-the-green-lines?/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 316 on 2013-10-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The box and green lines should always align. This looks like a rendering bug.

Here is a [pull-request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/745/visualize-moment-of-inertia-fix-203/diff) that may fix this problem.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on 2013-10-11**:
Thx Nate. And what is the supposed meaning of the them? The orientation of the principals?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-10-11**:
No, the green lines are just there as decoration, to distinguish the purple box as a COM visual. Here is the [code](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/80faa53ae5d4a43db44de49be999165f104a93a8/gazebo/rendering/COMVisual.cc?at=default#cl-70)